# Changes on archive-product.php doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to customize the standard woocommerce theme and so far that has worked well. I copied all template files from `/plugins/woocommerce/templates` to `/mytheme/woocommerce` and customized the files.

But when i'm change something in `archive-product.php` nothing happens? I even tried to customize this in the core files (`/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`) but i doesn't work.

I want to change the class of the `h1` heading: `<h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>`.

So i looked up **all** woocommerce template files, the class `page-title` occurs only in this one file (to prevent editing the wrong file).

**Edit:**

In detail, i want to customize the theme used in this path: http://example.com/product-category/mycategory

Comment: Do you have any caching plugin installed on your website?

Comment: No, i haven't installed any cache plugins.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Seems this is STILL an issue in Woocommerce. For anyone landing here, the following solution was working for me as of version 2.1.6.

Apparently the problem is due to the function woocommerce_content() outputting the wrong page for archive content.

I used the following to get around it:

replace woocommerce_content() in woocommerce.php with:

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
 woocommerce_content();
}else{
//For ANY product archive.
//Product taxonomy, product search or /shop landing
 woocommerce_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
}
```

Credit: found the solution [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/archive-productphp-template-overwrite-not-working)

Comment: It is by design see here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: this solution is obsolete now - woocommerce_content() doesn't exist in woocommerce.php

Comment: No, `woocommerce_content()` still exists in the latest version.

Comment: Even in 2020 this continues to be an issue. Thank you for your answer, found it after two days of searching. You are amazing!

Comment: Before using this solution, try adding support for woocommerce in the functions.php file as @IAteYourKitten pointed out below.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a nice solution - custom edits to plugin files would overwrite with update

Answer (score 62):

I tried all the above solutions, to no avail.  No matter what I did, the archive-product.php was not being used at all.  Instead, most woocommerce pages were using page.php from my theme.

The solution for me was to add theme support... Which, it's been a while since I used woocommerce, so I completely forgot about that.  But after adding the following line to my functions.php file, archive-product.php is now being used (/mytheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php) and I can update it, as I should be able to.

```
add_theme_support('woocommerce');
```

Comment: thanks for that insight. in my case i had issues with a filter being applied, not even a template overwrite. it was not working until i added the wc theme support. strange..

Comment: Works fine! Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, but thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Omg! I completely forgot about this! =PPP I was having troubles and now all strucuture is fixed! The woocommerce folder inside my theme is working great now and also the body class are back. Example: pressing ctrl+u to display the source code I can see now all the page types added to body class! Thanks so much!

Comment: If you add the theme support, then WooCommerce decides to always show a sidebar in your theme even if you don't have any. If you don't add theme support, there's no way to remove the category description hook. Great piece of software.

Comment: @Slevin This should be an accepted answer for anybody else who comes accross this issue :) Thanks

Comment: if your theme is already setup then add this code with ```after_setup_theme```. Works for me  ```function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() { add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); } add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' ); ```.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I fixed mine:

1. Delete woocommerce.php in your theme folder.
2. Copy TEMPLATE folder in woocommerce plugin dir, paste it in your THEME folder, and rename it to woocommerce.
3. Open the folder you just renamed, go to shop folder, and edit wrapper-start.php and wrapper-end.php.

Comment: Wow... this worked, but goes against everything according to the WooCommerce documentation for adding compatibility to a theme.  Is this a bug?  This seems like a scary work around but definitely works.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the woocommerce.php method you cannot customize archive-product. You must use the hooks method

> http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/
>   Please note: when creating woocommerce.php in your theme’s folder, you won’t be able to override  the woocommerce/archive-product.php custom template as woocommerce.php has the priority over  archive-product.php. This is intended to prevent display issues.

Answer (score 2):

you need to edit the file "taxonomy-product_cat.php" and add a conditional is_product_category( 'mycategory' ).

1. open your theme folder and add a new subfolder named "woocommerce" to it.
2. copy the files "archive-product.php" and "taxonomy-product_cat.php" from /plugins/woocommerce/templates to the woocommerce subfolder in your theme.
3. rename "archive-product.php" to "archive-mycategory.php" (or whatever you like, this will be the template file to the category).
4. open "taxonomy-product_cat.php" and wrap the  `wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );` with:

```php
    if (is_product_category( 'mycategory' )){
        wc_get_template( 'archive-mycategory.php' );
    }  else {
        wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For others searching here, doublecheck the path. It is for example not `/mytheme/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` but only `/mytheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. I didn't have to apply @Talk nerdy to me's patch or any other to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a custom Wordpress theme with Woocommerce and Elementor and I encountered the same error. I copied the archive-product.php from the original woocommerce directory and placed in into /mytheme/woocommerce/ directory. I then created a new product archive template through the Elementor template builder. I then added added this piece of code to functions.php:

```
function woocommerce_custom_archive_template( $template ) {
  if ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'archive-product.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
      return $new_template ;
    }
  }
  return $template;
}
```

This function is used to customize the WooCommerce product post type archive page template. It checks if the archive is for the product post type, and if it is, it looks for a custom archive-product.php template file in the theme folder. If the file exists, it loads the custom template instead of the default WooCommerce template. This function is necessary if you want to customize the product archive page template in your theme.

In combination with `add_theme_support('woocommerce');` this solved my issue. Hope it will help other developers in the future!