# WooCommerce Template Override for Archive-Product.php (Main Shop Page) Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I can't for the life of me manage to override the main shop page.

My understanding is that it's archive-product.php

I've attempted to copy it into the Woocommerce directory I created in my theme's root directory and modify it.  No dice.

I've also attempted to modify it directly in the Woocommerce plugin directory.  No dice there either.

I've even gone as far as adding an underscore before the archive-product.php file name in both locations (woocommerce directory and my theme template directory) in an attempt to hopefully BREAK it - just to see if I could impact SOME change - and that doesn't seem to have any effect either.

I'm not running any cache plugins and every other Woocommerce template file I've attempted to modify up until this point has worked fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You are doing this correctly. You'll have to double check the locations as per:

- Shop template is in
  `plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`
- You can copy to `my-themes/woocommerce/archive-product.php` to
  override the core woocommerce file.

Comment: Correct answer. This answer saved my time! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue, 
What worked for me, is removing the woocommerce.php file, because before, it applied the template woocommerce.php to the shop, and not the archive-product.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that when you updated to the newest version of WooCommerce, you have to "reinstall" the WooCommerce pages because the old system did not use the `wc_get_page_id()` function, which looks for the shop page.

Luckily this is super easy! Go to your admin, then to WooCommerce, then to System Status, then click on the Tools tab. Then click the button to the right of Install WooCommerce Pages. This will only install the missing WooCommerce pages and, get this, will reinstall the shop page with the proper `wc_get_page_id`.

NOTE: if you have content in the original WordPress shop page, although it didn't erase it for me, you might just want to copy the content first just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using the suggestion here - [Changes on archive-product.php doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353899/changes-on-archive-product-php-doesnt-work)

but, it seems like a bug to me.  WooCommerce claims that you need that root `woocommerce.php` page in order to incorporate the plugin into  your custom theme - http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/ - but, this does work.

I'd love to know the reasoning behind this.

Switching to the twentyeleve/twentytwelve theme's and trying to override the `archive-product.php` file in the same fashion worked great, but they don't include a native `woocommerce.php` file in their root directory either.  What gives?