# How to call different template for different category archive page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, archive

I have two categories in woocommerce One is "Men" and Other is "Women".

Be default woocommerce call archive-product.php for category archive page.

But I want to show different layout for each category archive page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can see how WooCommerce is filtering [`template_include`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-template-loader.php#L46-61) and will automatically look for taxonomy templates in the following order

`taxonomy-YOUR_TAXONOMY-YOUR_TERM.php`

then

`taxonomy-YOUR_TAXONOMY.php`

So in your example I believe you would create the following templates:

`taxonomy-product_cat-men.php`

and

`taxonomy-product_cat-women.php`

Answer (score 3):

Just answered this here: [changes-on-archive-product-php-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353899/changes-on-archive-product-php-doesnt-work/38167759#38167759)

you need to edit the file "taxonomy-product_cat.php" and add a conditional is_product_category( 'mycategory' ).

1. open your theme folder and add a new subfolder named "woocommerce" to it.
2. copy the files "archive-product.php" and "taxonomy-product_cat.php" from /plugins/woocommerce/templates to the woocommerce subfolder in your theme.
3. rename "archive-product.php" to "archive-mycategory.php" (or whatever you like, this will be the template file to the category).
4. open "taxonomy-product_cat.php" and wrap the wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); with:

   if (is_product_category( 'mycategory' )){
   wc_get_template( 'archive-mycategory.php' );
   } else { wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); }

Answer (score 1):

You should create different templates for different categories and then use them.

Have a look at here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95386/woocommerce-specific-template-for-product-category