# How to create different archive template for woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce for a wordpress site, I need to create different templates for different categories. I followed this answer, but it doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928010/3774595.

I create a new file "taxonomy-product_cat-66.php", where 66 is the ID of my category, but It doesn't work. Is there a way to make it works?

Comment: Please post your code for the new template. It's [difficult to provide constructive feedback without having more information about what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you might want to [ask this question on the Wordpress StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Did you check this tutorial? https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203106637-Creating-custom-category-templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see how WooCommerce is filtering [`template_include`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-template-loader.php#L46-61) and will automatically look for taxonomy templates in the following order

`taxonomy-YOUR_TAXONOMY-YOUR_TERM.php`

then

`taxonomy-YOUR_TAXONOMY.php`

Therefore you cannot use the Term ID, but rather should use the term slug. So for example men's and women's category archives would require the following templates:

`taxonomy-product_cat-men.php`

and

`taxonomy-product_cat-women.php`