# Woocommerce archive-product.php overwrite hack not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried this hack from a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353899/changes-on-archive-product-php-doesnt-work) thread:

Replace woocommerce_content() in woocommerce.php with:

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    woocommerce_content();
} else {
    //For ANY product archive.
    //Product taxonomy, product search or /shop landing
    woocommerce_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
}
```

This now loads the `archive-product.php` from the `/plugin` folder which is a step forward, but it should really load the archive-product.php from the `/myTheme` folder. I don't want to mess around in the plugin folder for obvious reasons...

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Your **archive-product.php** file should be in your theme folder, within a `/woocommerce` directory. So: `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`.

Comment: OMG yes, I had it in `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`. Silly me.. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure! I just added my comment as an answer. It would be great if you could upvote or select as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Just did it- thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **archive-product.php** file should be in your theme folder, within a `/woocommerce` directory. So: `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. It's a bit confusing, because the actual WooCommerce templates are within an additional `/templates` directory, in the plugin itself.

Read more about overriding WooCommerce templates in their documentation: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/